# rails activerecord objects persistence for a specified time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In a rails 3 app, I need to create objects who are persistent for specified time. For example, say I created an activerecord object (of a model) but need it to be around only for say 12 hours. The activerecord object needs to be automatically destroyed from the database after 12 hours. There is no need for the deletion to happen through controller, it could happen directly on the database. What is the best way to achieve this? There might be thousands of such objects getting created and destroyed at any timer and each needs to be destroyed at specified time.

I looked around and found some gems - whenever & delayed job. whenever is more of a wrapper on cron and hence not suitable considering the number of activerecord objects to be managed. I am yet to investigate 'delayed job' which uses background process, but wanted to get some feedback on available options.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delayed job seems like a good way to go, add after_save callback on your model that will queue up delayed job to delete it. use run_at => 12.hours.from_now

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run a cron/whenever job every few minutes that queries the database for objects where created_at > 12.hours.ago? Thus you manage to delete all objects by query instead of going one by one.

```
every 5.minutes do
  Model.where(:created_at > 12.hours.ago).delete_all
end
```

If you need to be more precise, I can imagine using Redis keys for your objects and setting the time expiration on keys at 12 hours, though you would need to figure out how to connect with Redis.

In any case, something needs to be observing the database for this to happen, or you have expiring keys.